# CMAKE project dependencies

Tags: cmake

I am trying to set up a build system using CMake for a moderately sized project which is made of several smaller projects, some of which have been developed externally. The directory structure I would like is something like this:

---

basedir

```
  |--libA
  |     |-src   ( .cxx, source files )
  |     |-libA  ( header files, such that #include statements are "libA/headerA.h" )
  |     |-bin   ( executable, binary, object files )
  |     |-build ( CMake output, makefiles, platform specific stuff, not in CVS/SVN )
  |     |-CMakeLists.txt
  |
  |--libB
  |     |-- ..similar structure
```

---

I think of libA and libB as separate projects. Potentially, libA's configuration would also describe linking to external libraries (like libxml2, etc) and set up appropriate link options and include paths for those packages. I would like to have libB depend on libB and be able to grab a set of macros to automatically append into, for example, it's LD_LIBRARY_PATH, INCLUDES variables, etc... such that it can link appropriately against libA and all that libA needs in a scalable manner.

I have worked with another configuration management tool which did this very well, but isn't becoming an industry standard and so would like to move to cmake. I haven't seen a good example of how CMake handles these interdependencies -- anyone know of a good starting place? Do I need to just 'include($(CMAKE_MODULES_PATH) libA/CMakeLists.txt)' or is there another file I need to create. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but creating a libAConfig.cmake as described here:
[How to create Project config file](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) might do the trick.

Comment: Not sure how making this file would help. Though we have such kind of setup in our project.